# Display coredata value in widgetkit - SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, core-data, widgetkit

I am trying to display my core data values in the widget kit however my values are not displayed. I am sharing my code below:

I was following different tutorials for the same task and thus had followed different ways to achieve the task. I tried app groups as well but couldn't succeed.

Result: The widget UI has been done but not even the static texts are displayed when I write the shared code.

My main purpose is to display the user details stored in the core data into my widget.

**Here is my code base :**

```
    struct Provider: AppIntentTimelineProvider {
        
        let managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<User> = User.fetchRequest()
        
        func placeholder(in context: Context) -> SimpleEntry {
            SimpleEntry(date: Date(), valueToDisplay: "dfbgdfb")
        }

        func snapshot(for configuration: ConfigurationAppIntent, in context: Context) async ->     SimpleEntry {
            SimpleEntry(date: Date(), valueToDisplay: "4534534")
        }
        
        func timeline(for configuration: ConfigurationAppIntent, in context: Context) async -> Timeline<SimpleEntry> {
            
            var entries: [SimpleEntry] = []

                let users = try? managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest)

                // Process fetched data and create SimpleEntry objects
                for user in users! {
                    let entry = SimpleEntry(date: Date(), valueToDisplay: user.userName ?? "")
                    entries.append(entry)
                }
            let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
            return timeline
        }
    }


struct SimpleEntry: TimelineEntry {
    let date: Date
    let valueToDisplay :  String
}

struct QuitSmokeAllWidgetEntryView : View {
    var entry: Provider.Entry
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

    var body: some View {
        
        //MARK: - QuitSmoke Widgets
        ZStack {
            Color("ThemeColor")
                .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
            VStack {
                Spacer()
               
                Text("Money Saved")
                Text(entry.valueToDisplay) // Display the core data value
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                Text("$0,0")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding()
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .background(Color("ThemeColor"))
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}

struct QuitSmokeAllWidget: Widget {
    let kind: String = "QuitSmokeAllWidget"

    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        AppIntentConfiguration(kind: kind, intent: ConfigurationAppIntent.self, provider: Provider(managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext())) { entry in
            QuitSmokeAllWidgetEntryView(entry: entry)
                .containerBackground(Color("ThemeColor"), for: .widget)
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is my code for Persistence.swift file:**

```
public extension URL {
    static func storeUrl(for appGroup:String, databaseName:String) -> URL {
        guard let fileConatiner = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: appGroup) else {
            print("Unable to create url for \(appGroup)")
            return URL(fileURLWithPath: "")
        }
        return fileConatiner.appendingPathComponent("\(databaseName).sqlite")
    }
}

    init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Quit_Smoking")
        
        if inMemory {
            container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first?.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
        } else {
            let url = URL.storeUrl(for: "group.com.quitSmoke", databaseName: "Quit_Smoking")
            let storeDescription = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: url)
            container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [storeDescription]
        }
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                print("ERRRORRR--->\(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        })
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide minimal working sample project for this issue. Then only others can easily run your project and support you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then [edit] your question.